# Solve cannot find table 0 error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, dataset

I don't know what is wrong with my code I keep getting this error "Cannot find table 0", in asp.net c#. I have used dataset.

**I wrote a stored procedure as below,**

```
If @mode='INSERT'
     Begin
     if exists(select 1 from COD_BLU_OPENING_VOLUME where target_dt=convert(date,getdate(),101) and JobID=@openJob)
                        Begin
                If not exists(select 1 from COD_BLU_INVENTORY with(nolock) where (JOBID=@job and STATUS='A' and TargetDt = convert(date,@targetdt,101)))
                    Begin
                        insert into COD_BLU_INVENTORY(JOBID,TargetDt,CarryOver,FreshVol,TotalVol,Status,UpdatedBy,UpdateDt) 
                        VALUES(@job,@targetdt,@CarryoverVol,@FreshVol,@TotalVol,'A',@Empcode,GETDATE())
                        select '1'
                    End
                else
                    Begin 
                        select'0'
                    End
            End     

         if not exists(select 1 from COD_BLU_OPENING_VOLUME where target_dt<=convert(date,getdate(),101) and JobID=@openJob)

            Begin
                insert into COD_BLU_OPENING_VOLUME(target_dt,JobID,Opening_Count,Updated_by,Updated_Dt,Pre_AssignedCount) 
                values(@openTarDt,@openJob,@openCnt,@openEmpcode,GETDATE(),@preOpenCnt)

                If not exists(select 1 from COD_BLU_INVENTORY with(nolock) where (JOBID=@job and STATUS='A' and TargetDt = convert(date,@targetdt,101)))
                    Begin
                        insert into COD_BLU_INVENTORY(JOBID,TargetDt,CarryOver,FreshVol,TotalVol,Status,UpdatedBy,UpdateDt) 
                        VALUES(@job,@targetdt,@CarryoverVol,@FreshVol,@TotalVol,'A',@Empcode,GETDATE())
                        select '0'
                    End
                else
                    Begin 
                        select'1'
                    End
            End

End
```

**my C# code as follows,**

```
if (btnSave.Text == "Save (F9)")
            {
                objBE.mode = "INSERT";
                objBE.carryoverVol = Convert.ToInt32(txtCarryOver.Text);
                objBE.freshVol = Convert.ToInt32(txtFreshVol.Text);
                objBE.totalVol = Convert.ToInt32(txtTotalVol.Text);
                objBE.job = ddljob.SelectedValue;
                DateTime temp = DateTime.ParseExact(txtTargetDate.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
                objBE.targetDate = Convert.ToDateTime(temp);
                objBE.empcode = Session["EMPCODE"].ToString();
                DateTime opentemp = DateTime.ParseExact(txtTargetDate.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
                objBE.openTarDt = Convert.ToDateTime(opentemp);
                objBE.openJob = ddljob.SelectedValue;
                hdnPreOpenCnt.Value = txtCarryOver.Text;
                objBE.preCnt = Convert.ToInt32(hdnPreOpenCnt.Value);
                string curDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy");
                if (txtTargetDate.Text != curDate)
                {
                    objBE.opneCount = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    objBE.opneCount = Convert.ToInt32(hdnOpenVol.Value);
                }
                objBE.openEmpcode = Session["EMPCODE"].ToString();
                ds = objBLL.FetchInventoryDetails(objBE);
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString() == "0")
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "check", "alert('The JOB is already mapped. Please check');", true);
                }
                else
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "saved", "alert('Saved Successfully');", true);
                    clearControls();
                }

            }
```

**fetchinventorydetails code:**

```
public DataSet FetchAssignmentDetails(BE objBE)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlParameter[] paramValue = new SqlParameter[]
        {
        new SqlParameter("@mode",objBE.mode),
        new SqlParameter("@job",objBE.job),
        new SqlParameter("@qaname",objBE.qcName),
        new SqlParameter("@targetdt",objBE.targetDate),
        new SqlParameter("@targetvalue",objBE.targetcount),
        new SqlParameter("@codername",objBE.coderName),
        new SqlParameter("@ProjID",objBE.ProjectId),
        new SqlParameter("@Empcode",objBE.empcode),
        new SqlParameter("@id",objBE.id),
        new SqlParameter("@startdt",objBE.startDate),
        new SqlParameter("@enddt",objBE.endDate)
        };
        SQLHelper.ExecuteDataSet(SQLHelper.CONN_STRING_NON_DTC, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "sp__Assignment", ds, "Assignment", paramValue);
        return ds;
    }
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Looks like `FetchInventoryDetails` isn't returning anything.

Comment: thanks u, did u happen to find any mistake in my codes.. @stuart

Comment: Can you share the code for `FetchInventoryDetails`

Comment: yes @richa garg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you don't have data returned in your dataset from your database.

its alway good to check dataset for table presence before accessing it to avoid exception of null reference. Also you need to put check on row count for table before accessing it to avoid no row at position 0 error.

put check before accessing table like below,

```
ds = objBLL.FetchInventoryDetails(objBE);
if(ds.Tables.Count > 0)
{                

if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString() == "0")
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),      "check", "alert('The JOB is already mapped. Please check');", true);
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),  "saved", "alert('Saved Successfully');", true);
                clearControls();
            }
}
}
```